# Timeout issue with Flink Stateful Functions with Azure Event Hub Kafaka endpoint

Tags: azure, apache-flink, azure-eventhub, flink-statefun

**Problem:**

Flink task manager reports: `apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata`

**Deployment overview:**

- A Java project to try out Stateful Functions.The streaming app reads messages from Kafka, processes messages and sends the final result to kafka egress.
- Deployed on Azure:
- Azure Event Hub (Kafka Endpoint) as ingress and egress
- Azure Kubernetes Service as k8s deployment
- Azure Data Lake Gen 2 as storage for checkpoint

Deployment is good, job manager and task manager has been launched, then I see task failed to run due to the exception

**Diagnostics:**

1. I created a simple Java consumer with the identical kafka config,
   just with a different consumer group. The Java app works **well both
   on my laptop and in AKS** (deployed in the same namespace as the
   stateful function app is) So I get a conclusion that the Event Hub
   and my kafka config are both good.
2. I checked the task manager log (kubectl logs xxx), and the kafka properties have been correctly loaded. The sasl.jaas.config shows as `"sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]"` but I assume this is by design.

**My Kafka Settings:**

I'm using the following config:

```
kind: io.statefun.kafka.v1/ingress
spec:
  id: io.streaming/eventhub-ingress
  address: xxxx.servicebus.windows.net:9093
  consumerGroupId: group-receiver-00
  startupPosition:
    type: group-offsets
  topics:
    - topic: streaming-topic-rec-32
      valueType: streaming.types/rec
      targets:
        - streaming.fns/bronze_rec
    - topic: streaming-topic-eng-32
      valueType: streaming.types/eng
      targets:
        - streaming.fns/bronze_eng
  properties:
    - request.timeout.ms: 60000
    - security.protocol: SASL_SSL
    - sasl.mechanism: PLAIN
    - sasl.jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="primary connection string of the event hub ns";
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved after reducing replicas of task manager. No config changed